# callback and onthreadfinish

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, delegates

I am just asking for the cleanest way to have a callback to update the GUI when a thread is running and a method that will be called when the thread has finished.

So in my example, I have a **Counter** class (this is the task), and 2 delegates, 1 for callback, 1 for finishing of the thread.

It all works fine, but I have the feeling that this is not the best/cleanest/.. way to do it.

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, I'm having a hard time understanding the concept of a delegate and threads threads since I haven't started programming that long ago.

**The counter class**

```
class Counter
{
    private PrintCallback cb;
    private OnActionFinish oaf;

    public void SetCallback(PrintCallback c)
    {
        this.cb = c;
    }

    public void SetOnFinished(OnActionFinish f)
    {
        this.oaf = f;
    }

    public void Count()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            cb(i);
        }
        oaf();
    }

}
```

**And my main form**

```
public delegate void PrintCallback(int i);
public delegate void OnActionFinish();

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PrintCallback cb = new PrintCallback(Print);
        OnActionFinish otf = new OnActionFinish(Finished);
        Counter c = new Counter();
        c.SetCallback(cb);
        c.SetOnFinished(otf);
        Thread t = new Thread(c.Count);
        t.Start();
        label1.Text = "Thread started";
    }

    private void Print(int i)
    {
        if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { 
                textBox1.Text += i + "\r\n";
            });
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text += i + "\n";
        }
    }

    private void Finished()
    {
        if (label1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { 
                label1.Text = "Thread finished";
                textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
                textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
            });
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = "Thread finished";
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the BackgroundWorker class?  It does all this.

Comment: @Hans: I suggest you post the solution with sourc code with uses the `BackgroundWorker` :)

Comment: Nah, we really don't need to add example number 10,001 here.

Comment: Does your code HAS to run on a thread, or can it also run on a threadpool thread?

Answer (score 1):

To refactor your code, using your own techniques, it could become something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = "Thread started";
        Counter c = new Counter(Print, Finished);
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(c.Count)).Start();
    }

    private void Print(int i)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
            Invoke(new Action<int>(Print), i);
        else
            textBox1.Text += i + "\r\n";
    }

    private void Finished()
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new Action(Finished));
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = "Thread finished";
            textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
            textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
        }
    }
}


class Counter
{
    private readonly Action<int> _output;
    private readonly Action _finished;

    public Counter(Action<int> output, Action finished)
    {
        _output = output;
        _finished = finished;
    }

    public void Count()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            _output(i);
        _finished();
    }
}
```